# LXD Snap stuck on "undoing"

Tags: snap, lxd, cluster

I use LXD for my cluster and I can't access it for a couple of days, because the LXD versions are incompatible across the cluster. In one of the node it's upgraded to 4.3; but on the other one, it's still 4.2.

I tried to upgrade it manually by `sudo snap refresh lxd`, but it returns:

```
error: snap "lxd" has "auto-refresh" change in progress
```

I checked the status via `snap changes` and it tells me:

```
ID   Status   Spawn                     Ready  Summary
57   Undoing  yesterday at 05:24 +0430  -      Auto-refresh snap "lxd"
```

Trying to abort this via `sudo snap abort 57` has no results and the process is still there.

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 1):

By default, `snapd` performs a package refresh within 24 hours of the availability. The installation is spaced out within 24 hours in order to lessen the load of the servers.

In your case, you should use the `snapd` features to get `lxd` updated at specific times, https://snapcraft.io/docs/keeping-snaps-up-to-date#heading--controlling-updates

Considering the severity of this issue, I recommend to ask at https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/ You may get help from the LXD maintainers.

Comment: Ain't this a Snap-only problem? 

Comment: It is indeed a snap issue. But it directly relates to how LXD works.